# Processing a json HttpResponse using Ajax

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, httpresponse

I have sent a HttpResponse from views.py to an HTML page. However, while loading the directed page it only shows the JSON object and not the actual HTML page with the details.

This is how the page looks after the request is completed
[image]

These are my expectations for how the data should be displayed
[image]

views.py

```
def tracker(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        oid = request.POST.get('oid', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        try:
            order = Orders.objects.filter(order_id = oid, email = email)
            if len(order)>0:
                update = OrderUpdate.objects.filter(order_id = oid)
                updates = []
                for item in update:
                    updates.append({'text': item.update_desc, 'time':item.timestamp})
                    response = json.dumps(updates, default = str)
                return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse({})
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse({})

    return render(request, 'shop/tracker.html')
```

tracker.html

```
{% include 'shop/basic.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="col my-4">
        <h2>My Awesome Cart Tracker - Enter yuor Order ID and Email address to track your order</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="#" id="trackerForm">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="Oid">Order Id</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="oid" name="oid" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="email" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Track Order</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col my-4">
        <h2>Your Order Status</h2>
        <div id="items" class="my-4">
            <ul class="list-group my-4" id="items">
                Enter your order ID and Email and click Track Order to find details about your order!
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block js %}
    <script>
        $('#trackerForm').submit(function (event) {
            $('#items').empty();
            var formData = {
                'orderId': $('input[name = oid]').val(),
                'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/shop/tracker/',
                data: formData,
                encode: true
            })
                .done(function (data) {
                    updates = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (updates.length > 0 & updates != {}) {
                        for (i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
                            let text = updates[i]['text'];
                            let time = updates[i]['time'];
                            mystr = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    ${text}
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">${time}</span>
                </li>`
                            $('#items').append(mystr);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        mystr = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Sorry, we are not able to fetch this order ID and email. Kindly recheck the Order ID and email.</li>`
                        $('#items').append(mystr);
                    }

                });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `method` and `action` attributes from `<form method="POST" action="#" id="trackerForm">` tag and keep it as `<form id="trackerForm">`?

Comment: From your tracker.html remove action attribute from form and change button type to button istead of submit,  and istead of `$('#trackerForm').submit`, do `$('#trackerForm').click` or simply try `event.preventDefault()` in your submit handler this should solve the issue

Comment: I have tried removing action attribute, it didn't work for my case. The method attribute can't be removed as it's been referred in views.py file. @PrathapReddy

Comment: I tried following your suggestion modified the button type and used ```$('#trackerForm').click```, but it did no good there weren't any results of clicking the button. And related to ```event.preventDefault()```, it's already there in the code. @Suryan

Comment: I am not familiar with `python/django` code. I believe problem might be present at the line **return HttpResponse(response)** inside `if` block. You might need to return with `html` page there. Contol will never reach to the line **return render(request, 'shop/tracker.html')**. Please ignore this comment if I interpreted your code wrongly.

Comment: By the time you are sending the ajax request you specified it is post request, no need to define in form tag, that will be the post request, just remove method, and action from the form, change button type to button and .submit to .click. And you must understand how ajax works and the difference between button type and form submission

Answer (score 0):

Put event.preventDefault() before the execution of Ajax request.

By the time your Ajax request returned the httpresponse the submit button default action was  triggered to the Dom has been changed before you could tell the Dom to not change.